# Redirection error with google load balancer

Tags: ssl, mod-rewrite, google-cloud-platform, url-rewriting, load-balancing

I'm trying to setup Google Load Balancer and couldn't get it work. It produces either 502 or 302 error.

Wanting to direct www to non-www, http to https.

This is my rewrite rule

```
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
    <VirtualHost _default_:80>
      DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
      Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
      <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPass /.well-known !
      </IfModule>
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Google Load Balancer has only 1 backend service. Backend is configured for HTTP and frontend is HTTPS.

- The instance is accessible via both instance's IP and load balancer's IP
- www to non-www is not working.
- Http gives a 404 error.
- https gives a 502 / 302 error.

Are the rewrite rules all wrong?

Comment: Do you use an external HTTPS load balancer?

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere yes, I'm using external HTTPS load balancer.

Comment: So why don't you use this? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks. I'm thinking of doing it at a server level. For learning purpose, is there a  benefit of using LB to achieve redirection? And LB incurs a fee?

Comment: A load balancer incur fees but it's mandatory to deploy a production grade application. In addition, it's managed by Google, not by you!!